# Selenium JavaScript to continue loop after exception

Tags: javascript, selenium, try-catch

```
for (let n = 0; n < someNumber; n++){ 
  try {
    driver.get(url[n]);
    driver.findElement(By.css("selector"));
  } catch (err){
    console.log(url[n] + "did not load");
  }
}
```

I am trying to loop through web pages in Javascript. I am looking for an element on the page. If I cannot find the element, I want it to log the URL and continue the loop. The problem is that my code just stops at the `findElement` and will stop execution. It never reaches my catch block. I just get the error below:

`NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong `selector`, If you want to locate the element using **`cssSelector`** then you should write something like this :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Location of your WebElement"));
Example : 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id=email]"));
```

**In place of :**  `driver.findElement(By.css("selector"));`

`findElement` will throw an error if the element you're searching for doesn't exist.
And if there is only one element you are looking for then you should write `findElement` or if there are many elements present then use `findElements`

Comment: This is in JavaScript, not Java. JavaScript Selenium locator for css correctly works the way i wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

This error has come as you have used invalid locator. Your locator should be **cssSelector** not **css**.

Change this line **driver.findElement(By.css("selector"))** to 
**driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selector"))** and your program would be working as expected.

Comment: This is in JavaScript, not Java. This is the correct syntax in JavaScript for locating CSS.